# How do I shrink/change BIOS_RVY partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, bios

I recently bought a new internal SSD. I used the manufacturer's software to clone the original SSD onto the new one. That seems to have worked without much issue, but the BIOS_RVY partition is huge and takes up the majority of the 2 TB. And because it's the BIOS, I can't seem to change and allocate the excess storage to the D drive.

[Screenshot of my Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOZl9.png)

The top drive is the new one (2 TB). This is a better SSD, so I want to boot from this drive and keep most of my data on it. The other drive (the one that came in the laptop) is the bottom one. I don't need to keep any data on it, and would prefer that it just be a single partition purely for storage.

How can I shrink the BIOS partition on the 2 TB SSD (top right partition) to the 19 GB that it was on the original drive? For reference, my drive is the 2 TB Sabrent Rocket-Q. The software I used to clone the drive is Acronis True Image.

Comment: That’s just a partition label.  It absolutely IS NOT the firmware for the device.  You will be unable to combine the 1.4 TB partition with your 500 GB using Disk Management.  Third-party partitioning software must be used

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for third party software? Also, I have the option to delete this partition. If it's not the BIOS/firmware partition, would there be any issue in deleting it?

Comment: Questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope